# Restriction of creating Web apps and function apps which violate azure security policies

Tags: azure, azure-security

Is there a way I could prevent others from creating web apps and function apps without meeting azure security standard. for an example i need to stop other azure admins creating web apps and function apps without enabling Https or FTPS for the resources. Currently what I have to do is get the recommendation from security center and manually enable HTTPS only and FTPS for function apps. please help

Answer (score 1):

You should use Azure Policy for this. There are built in policies for HTTPS and FTPS only. You can also create custom policies to meet your organizational needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/policy-reference